# Symfony DateTimeType always failing validation with split fields

Tags: symfony

I believe I have found an error when splitting the DateTimeType into two fields. I am unable to pass form validation. Can someone point out if I am missing something or replicate this?

Here is a snip from my alertType.php

```
            ->add('from', DateTimeType::class,[
            'date_widget'=>'single_text',
            'time_widget'=>'single_text',
            // date and time error, whole date string provided
            'date_format'=>'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a', 
            'input'=>'string',
            'attr'=>['class'=>'js-datetime-input'],
            'html5'=>false,
            'required'=>true,

        ])
        ->add('till', DateTimeType::class,[
            'date_widget'=>'single_text',
            'time_widget'=>'single_text',
            'input'=>'string',
            // just date string provided, error only on time
            'date_format'=>'MM/dd/yyyy',
            'attr'=>['class'=>'js-datetime-input'],
            'html5'=>false,
            'required'=>true,

        ])
```

Here is an image from the profiler showing the two errors on from, and one on till due to splitting the date and time.

[image]

my form.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(alertForm) }}
    {{ form_row(alertForm.type) }}
    {{ form_row(alertForm.text) }}
    {{ form_row(alertForm.from) }}

    {{ form_row(alertForm.till) }}

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Save</button>
{{ form_end(alertForm) }}
```

Here is the form showing that I am getting only the error if supplying the date part on the **till**. I believe there is an issue when both fields are split.

[image]

Comment: I have noticed if I keep just the date formatting in the alertType, "MM/dd/yyy", it removed one of the errors. It seems splitting the fields, breaks the date_format option.

Comment: Yes, your provided value is `10/18/2018` which does not match the format. I can't tell why the time is not part of the value, though. How do you render the form, i.e. how does the twig-template look?

Comment: @dbrumann thank you for the prompt comment. I have updated the question to be a bit more clear and added the twig code. It is very basic. It still seems that it has to do with splitting the date and time fields in two, which breaks the date_format part.

Comment: It works fine if widget is set to single_text and format is "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", however I wish to use split fields.

Comment: <strike>Please try the submitted answer.</strike> (Sorry I didn't see your comment) Could you please add the content of `$request->query` to your question, to see what the submitted data looks like in the request?

Comment: I can see that you add the `js-datetime-input` class to your input. Can it be that you are using a JavaScript library that modifies the date (format) before the submission?

Comment: Rereading the description it seems that the issue is how you submit the time. The `TimeType` does not support 12-hour times. So you should just submit `12:00` instead of `12:00 am`.

Comment: FYI, there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6587) to support 12H formats too, but this is not the case yet.

Comment: @xabbuh, Yes I am using a jquery DatePicker and timepicker.io jquery extension for a time picker. This make time entry easier for users and less error prone. I think I am just going to create two unmapped fields and crate a dateTime object from the concatenated string and handle validation manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, though seems a bit hackish

The problem lies in that when you split the DateTimeType into its two fields the format option no longer works as the TimeType does not have a format option, it only accepts 24 hour format.

The solution to having split DateTimeType with a 12 hour format is to split the input between DateType for your dates, and use DateTimeType for time inputs to use the format option provided by the DateTimeType.

Here is a snip from my formBuilder

```
->add('fromDate',DateType::class,array(
    'format'=>'MM/dd/yyyy',
    'widget'=>'single_text',
    'attr'=>['class'=>'js-datepicker','placeholder'=>'mm/dd/yyyy'],
    'required'=>true
))
->add('fromTime',DateTimeType::class,[
    'widget'=>'single_text',
    'format'=>'hh:mm a',
    'attr'=>['class'=>'js-timepicker','placeholder'=>'type or use picker, hh:mm am'],
    'required'=>true
])
->add('tillDate',DateType::class,array(
    'format'=>'MM/dd/yyyy',
    'widget'=>'single_text',
    'attr'=>['class'=>'js-datepicker','placeholder'=>'mm/dd/yyyy'],
    'required'=>true
))
->add('tillTime',DateTimeType::class,[
    'widget'=>'single_text',
    'format'=>'hh:mm a',
    'attr'=>['class'=>'js-timepicker','placeholder'=>'type or use picker, hh:mm am'],
    'required'=>true
])
```

Then in your controller you would merge the two DateTime objects and set the value of your entity.

```
$fromDate = $form->get('fromDate')->getData();
$fromTime = $form->get('fromTime')->getData();
$tillDate = $form->get('tillDate')->getData();
$tillTime = $form->get('tillTime')->getData();

$mergeFrom = new \DateTime($fromDate->format('m/d/Y').' '.$fromTime->format('h:i a'));
$mergeTill = new \DateTime($tillDate->format('m/d/Y').' '.$tillTime->format('h:i a'));

$alert->setFrom($mergeFrom);
$alert->setTill($mergeTill);
```

Since my entity only stores the single field, we also need to use a couple extra properties on the entity to use Assertions on them

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="FROM_DATE", type="datetime")
 */
private $from;


/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
private $fromDate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
private $fromTime;
```

Hope this helps anyone else wanting to split their DateTimeTypes into separate fields for user input.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use `format` instead of `data_format` : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#reference-forms-type-date-format

Comment: I have attempted that and no change.

Comment: The `format` option is only taken into account if the `widget` option is set to `single_text` which is not the case here (and which you cannot do if you want to have separate inputs for date and time).